# Header authentication failed in Laravel API request on live server

Tags: php, laravel-5

Here is my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Things are working fine on local but its not accepting header on live server.

Comment: What's the specific error/behavior you're seeing?

Comment: (Side note for anyone wondering, this is the [default Laravel `.htaccess`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/.htaccess), not something custom.)

Comment: I am facing a similar issue, not able to get token which is being sent by the client in the header. "Authorization": "Bearer TOKEN" .

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this ?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.)
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I could also see `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` is repeated twice

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` is repeated intentionally !